# Filebeat/Logstash remove unwanted fields & values from output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

My Filebeat configuration is very simple -

```
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - C:\log\FilebeatInputTest.txt

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["http://X.X.X.X:XXXX"]
```

if I write something in `ilebeatInputTest.txt` like - `This is from Filebeat`

I get output in Elastic search something like - 
`.......
"index": "logstash-"
"source" : {
    "@timestamp": "2017-05-19T06:41:02.663Z",
    "beat": {
        "hostname": "CHITTARS02",
        "name": "CHITTARS02",
        "version": "5.4.0"
    },
    "input_type": "log",
    "message": "This is from Filebeat",
    "offset": 23,
    "source": "C:\\log\\FilebeatInputTest.txt",
    "type": "log"
}
.....`

My pipeline is `Filebeat(monitoring FilebeatInputTest.txt) > Logstash > Elasticsearch`

`logstash.cnf`  as follows -

```
input {

    beats {
        port => 25000
    }
}
output {

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://xx.xx.xx.xx:XX"]
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
    }
}
```

Problem : Can I remove all unwanted keys & values from output? That is, I want my output should be something like -

`.......
"index": "logstash-"
"source" : {
    "message": "This is from Filebeat",
}
......`

I want to remove `"@timestamp", "beat","input_type""offset","source","type"`

I tried with following -

```
filter{
    prune {
        blacklist_names => ["@timestamp", "beat","input_type""offset","source","type"]
    }

}
```

And

```
filter{
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["@timestamp", "beat","input_type""offset","source","type"]
    }
}
```

But no help, results are same

Comment: I have been looking for something at the filebeat end before send. have you had any luck?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the correct method, but there's a typo in your remove_field list. You missed a comma. It should be:

```
filter{
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "@timestamp", "beat", "input_type", "offset", "source", "type" ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to remove these fields with **[filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/drop-fields.html)**.

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - drop_fields:
    fields: ["type", "@version", "offset", "tags"]
```

Answer (score 0):

May guess is that you forget to put the port in quotes; that is instead of  `25000` used `"25000"`. Try this

```
input {

    beats {
        port => "25000"
    }
}

filter{
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["@timestamp", "beat","input_type","offset","source","type","@version","host","tags"]
    }
}

output {

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://xx.xx.xx.xx:XX"]
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
    }
}
```

Input

```
This is from Filebeat
```

Output

```
{
    "_index" : "logstash-",
    "_type" : "logs",
    "_id" : "AVwglLbLfqaeaIoZluvE",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "message" : "This is from Filebeat"
    }
}
```

I also removed the fields `"@version","host"` and `"tags"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response, 
but, if i use - 
filter{
        mutate {
                remove_field => ["offset", "input_type", "beat", "host", "source", "type", "tags"]
        }
}

i get this o/p -
{
        "_index" : "logstash-2017.05.31",
        "_type" : "logs",
        "_id" : "AVxem68fw204zcLHaGHa",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2017-05-31T13:04:37.730Z",
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : "Aare Samba kitna admi tha?"
        }
      }

Comment: But when i add "@timestamp", "@version", as -
filter{
        mutate {
                remove_field => ["offset", "input_type", "beat", "host", "source", "type", "tags", "@timestamp", "@version"]
        }
}

Logstash is exiting with following error - 
An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: timestamp field is missing>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/ext/JrubyEventExtLibrary.java:202:in `sprintf'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-6.3.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:153:in `event_action
..................

Comment: In all cases my input is as follows - 

{
        "_index" : "logstash-2",
        "_type" : "log",
        "_id" : "AVxeaCoN",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2017-05-31T10:23:53.436Z",
          "offset" : 11,
          "@version" : "1",
          "input_type" : "log",
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "elk-",
            "name" : "elk-chitta",
            "version" : "5.4.0"
          },
          "message" : "Hi Elastic",
          .............
        }
      }